# Оценка сайта в звездочках.

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществить на сайте возможность оставлять оценку. То-есть в футере будет возможность нажимать на определенную звездочку и тем самым оставлять оценку.

Comment: надо скачать плагин и почитать инструкцию по его настройке =)

Comment: Думаю что у тс больше вопросов по серверной части)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну [вот](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=467) к примеру

Comment: Какая сложная обёртка для $stars += $starvalue :-)